# Failure to Paste in a new Excel File/Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i am attempting to write a script that goes over a specific column and then copies all rows containing the value of "rejected" in said column to a new excel file/workbook.

Everything seems to work just fine except for the actual Paste command which fails every time.

The code:

Sub button()

```
  Dim x As String
  Dim found As Boolean
  strFileFullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
  strFileFullName = Replace(strFileFullName, ".xlsm", "")
  strFileFullName = strFileFullName + "_rejected.xlsx"
 ' MsgBox strFileFullName
  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set obook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
  Set oSheet = obook.Worksheets(1)
  oSheet.Name = "Results"

  ' Select first line of data.
  Range("E2").Select
  ' Set search variable value.
  x = "rejected"
  ' Set Boolean variable "found" to false.
  found = False
  ' Set Do loop to stop at empty cell.
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
     ' Check active cell for search value.
     If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
     Exit Do
     End If
     If ActiveCell.Value = x Then
        found = True

        rowToCopy = ActiveCell.Row
        ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Copy

        oSheet.Range("A1").Select
        lastrow = oSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    '   oSheet.Rows(1).Select.PasteSpcial

     End If
     ' Step down 1 row from present location.
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

      Loop
   ' Check for found.
      If found = True Then
         MsgBox "Value found in cell " & ActiveCell.Address
      Else
         MsgBox "Value not found"
      End If
      obook.SaveAs strFileFullName
      obook.Close
End Sub
```

Any idea why i keep failing with the paste function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, no selects involved.

```
 Sub AddWB()
    Dim nwBk As Workbook, WB As Workbook, Swb As String
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, sh As Worksheet

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Rws = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(sh.Cells(2, 5), sh.Cells(Rws, 5))

    Set nwBk = Workbooks.Add(1)
    Swb = WB.Path & "\" & Mid(WB.Name, 1, Len(WB.Name) - 5) & ".xlsx"
    MsgBox Swb

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        If c = "x" Then c.EntireRow.Copy nwBk.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next c

    nwBk.SaveAs Filename:=Swb

End Sub
```

[XLorate.com](http://xlorate.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `PasteSpecial` command might fail because it's spelled incorrectly. At any rate, if you've got a lot of rows, you should consider something faster than looping through them.

This uses AutoFilter to copy all rows meeting the criteria in one pass. It will also copy the header row. If that's not what you want, you can delete row 1 of the new worksheet after the copy:

```
Sub CopyStuff()
Dim SearchString As String
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbTarget As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
SearchString = "rejected"
With wsSource
    Found = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("E:E"), SearchString) > 0
    If Not Found Then
        MsgBox SearchString & " not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add(1)
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(1)
    wsTarget.Name = "Results"
    .Range("E:E").AutoFilter
    LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("E:E").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=SearchString
    .Range("E1:E" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A1")
End With
wbTarget.SaveAs Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", "_rejected.xlsx")
wbTarget.Close
End Sub
```

I didn't use your code to create a new Excel instance, as I couldn't see why that would be needed here, and it could cause problems. (For example,yYou don't kill the instance in your original code.)